# Relationship between notes and tags

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 3 objects and 3 models. The note, have many tags, and every tags must have one note. So, I have a `note_tag_list` to store the tags and notes relationship.

The program creates a note, with some tags.

First, I create a note object, and put it into the model. And I get back the object from the model. I create the tag if it doesn't exist. Then, I read back the tag object from the DB. And use all the tags and note to create new `note_tag_list` object, and put this object to the model.

But I think it seems very complex for my flow. Any ways to do it more elegant? Thank you.

```
//load all the object
$this->load->library('obj_note'); 
$this->load->library('obj_tag');  
$this->load->library('obj_note_tag_list'); 

//load all the model
$this->load->model('note_model');  
$this->load->model('tag_model');  
$this->load->model('note_tag_list_model'); 

//create a note object
$aNewUserNote    =new obj_note();

//set the object information
$user_id         =get_current_user_id();
$title           =$this->input->post('ui_title_input');
$content_url     =$this->input->post('ui_url_input');
$content         =$this->input->post('ui_textarea');
$right           =RIGHT_NOTE_PUBLIC;
$status          =STATUS_NOTE_ACTIVE;   

$aNewUserNote->set_user_id($user_id);
$aNewUserNote->set_title($title);
$aNewUserNote->set_content_url($content_url);
$aNewUserNote->set_content($content);
$aNewUserNote->set_right($right);
$aNewUserNote->set_status($status);

$aNewlyCreateNoteId = 0; 

if(!$this->note_model->create_note_by_note($aNewUserNote, $aNewlyCreateNoteId))
{          
    //create success
    return;
}   

//get back the object from the model
$aNewlyCreateObj = $this->note_model->read_note_by_note_id($aNewlyCreateNoteId);


$aTagNameString = $this->input->post('ui_tag');
$tagsStringArray = $this->convert_tags_string_to_lower_case_string_array($aTagNameString);

$aTagArray = array();  
$createNewTagIsSuccess = FALSE;

//Create New Tag
for($i = 0; $i < count($tagsStringArray); $i++)
{   
    $aTagObj = $this->tag_model->read_tag_by_tag_name($tagsStringArray[$i]);
    if($aTagObj == NULL)
    {
        $aNewTag =new obj_tag();
        $aNewTag->set_create_user_id($user_id);
        $aNewTag->set_tag_name($tagsStringArray[$i]);

        if(!$this->tag_model->create_tag_by_tag($aNewTag)) //create tag fail
        {
          $createNewTagIsSuccess = FALSE;  
        }
    }
}  

//Read all the tag
for($j = 0; $j < count($tagsStringArray); $j++)
{ 
    $aTagObj = $this->tag_model->read_tag_by_tag_name($tagsStringArray[$j]);
    $aTagArray[count($aTagArray)] = $aTagObj;
}                                            


//Make the note, and tag have relationship
for($k = 0; $k < count($aTagArray); $k++)
{                                       
    $theTagObj = $aTagArray[$k];          


    $aNoteTagList = new obj_note_tag_list();
    $aNoteTagList->set_note_id($aNewlyCreateObj[0]->get_id());
    $aNoteTagList->set_tag_id($theTagObj[0]->get_id());

    $this->note_tag_list_model->create_note_tag_list_by_note_tag_list($aNoteTagList);
}
```

Comment: I started to give it a try, but not knowing your objects and return types/values, its pretty much impossible. There are a few things I can spot straight away (like setting a var to another var before you use it, and using `for` where you should use `foreach`), but that's all I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

**This:**

```
//set the object information
$user_id         =get_current_user_id();
$title           =$this->input->post('ui_title_input');
$content_url     =$this->input->post('ui_url_input');
$content         =$this->input->post('ui_textarea');
$right           =RIGHT_NOTE_PUBLIC;
$status          =STATUS_NOTE_ACTIVE;   

$aNewUserNote->set_user_id($user_id);
$aNewUserNote->set_title($title);
$aNewUserNote->set_content_url($content_url);
$aNewUserNote->set_content($content);
$aNewUserNote->set_right($right);
$aNewUserNote->set_status($status);
```

Should be rewritten as **this**

```
// create and populate note object
$note = new obj_note();           
$note->set_user_id(get_current_user_id());
$note->set_title($this->input->post('ui_title_input'));
$note->set_content_url($this->input->post('ui_url_input'));
$note->set_content($this->input->post('ui_textarea'));
$note->set_right(RIGHT_NOTE_PUBLIC);
$note->set_status(STATUS_NOTE_ACTIVE);
```

Other than that, my comment on your question will explain the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a constructor for your object:

```
//create a note object
$aNewUserNote    =new obj_note(get_current_user_id(),
                               $this->input->post('ui_title_input'),
                               $this->input->post('ui_url_input'),
                               $this->input->post('ui_textarea'),
                               STATUS_NOTE_ACTIVE
                              );
```

Same thing for your tag:

```
    $aNewTag =new obj_tag($user_id, $tagsStringArray[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some idea to improve the code a little bit:

1, I wouldn't count the size of the array in every iteration. So I'd change

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($tagsStringArray); $i++) { ... }
```

to

```
$size = count($tagsStringArray)
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) { ... }
```

2, Use guard clauses:

```
//Create New Tag
for($i = 0; $i < count($tagsStringArray); $i++)
{   
    $aTagObj = $this->tag_model->read_tag_by_tag_name($tagsStringArray[$i]);
    if($aTagObj != NULL) {
        continue;
    }

    $aNewTag = new obj_tag();
    $aNewTag->set_create_user_id($user_id);
    $aNewTag->set_tag_name($tagsStringArray[$i]);

    if(!$this->tag_model->create_tag_by_tag($aNewTag)) //create tag fail
    {
      $createNewTagIsSuccess = FALSE;  
    }

}
```

3, The following comments could be function names:

```
//Create New Tag
//Read all the tag
//Make the note, and tag have relationship
```

For example:

```
function readAllTags($tagsStringArray) {
    $aTagArray = array();  
    for($j = 0; $j < count($tagsStringArray); $j++)
    { 
        $aTagObj = $this->tag_model->read_tag_by_tag_name($tagsStringArray[$j]);
        $aTagArray[count($aTagArray)] = $aTagObj;
    }  
    return $aTagArray;
}
```

It makes the code flatten and easier to read: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html

4, Use the value of `$createNewTagIsSuccess` or omit the variable. The code set it to `FALSE` before the *create new tag* loop and the loop sometimes set it to `FALSE` again. It looks little bit weird. (Maybe a bug? No code uses this flag.)

```
$createNewTagIsSuccess = FALSE;
```

5, I agree with *@Loki Astari* about constructors. Furthermore, *Consider static factory methods instead of constructors* (See Martin Fowler: Effective Java Second Edition, Item 1.)

6, AFAIK the index in following is unnecessary:

```
$aTagArray[count($aTagArray)] = $aTagObj;
```

So use

```
$aTagArray[] = $aTagObj;
```